# Is it possible to filter objects in Weaviate based on an operator that compares two properties?

Tags: weaviate

From the [Weaviate Python v4 client documentation](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/client-libraries/python), it appears that Weaviate filters can operate on a property name and a literal value.  Is it possible to filter on a logical operator comparing two properties?  For example,

```
mismatches=Filter.by_property("property_1").not_equal(some-way-to-reference-property_2-in-the-same-object)

some_collection.query.fetch_objects(filters=mismatches).objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Duda from Weaviate here.

This is not possible as of now. Could you open a feature request in our repo?
https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/new/choose

This will help us understand it better, check about other users wanting the same feaure and track it's way into [roadmap](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/roadmap)

Thanks!